# Tensor product of multiplications

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $P_1, P_2$ be two $k$-algebras and denote by $\Delta_{P_i}\colon P_i\times P_i \to P_i$ $(i=1,2)$ their multiplications. Let $P_1 \otimes_k P_2$ be the tensor product of $P_1$ and $P_2$. Is the multiplication in $P_1 \otimes_k P_2$ the tensor product, in any reasonable sense, of $\Delta_{P_1}$ and $\Delta_{P_2}$?

My worry comes from the fact that I am not used to tensoring maps other than algebra homomorphisms.

Comment: If $p_1 \in P_1$ and $p_2 \in P_2$, $\Delta_{P_1\otimes P_2}(\cdot, p_1\otimes p_2) = \Delta_{P_1}(\cdot,p_1) \otimes \Delta_{P_2}(\cdot, p_2)$. So, if we denote, for any $k$-algebra $P$, $\phi_P$ to be the map sending $p \in P$ to $\Delta_{P}(\cdot, p)$ (the "curryfication" of $\Delta_P$), then it looks like $\phi_{P_1\otimes P_2} = \phi_{P_1} \otimes \phi_{P_2}$. Is it something like this you were looking for ?

Comment: Well almost : $P_1\otimes P_2 \otimes P_1 \otimes P_2 \simeq P_1 \otimes P_1 \otimes P_2 \otimes P_2$, and since $\Delta_{P_i}$ is essentially a map $P_i\otimes P_i \to P_i$, you do get that in a very reasonable sense, $\Delta_{P_1} \otimes \Delta_{P_2}$ is a lot lile the multiplication on $P_1\otimes P_2$